# Showing a dialog when TopBar Back Arrow gets clicked in Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to figure out how to show a Dialog when the user presses the backarrow in my TopBar.
For example an "Are you sure you want to discard your changes" Dialog.

I'm using a single Scaffold with a BottomNavBar and a TopBar. It hides the BottomNavBar and displays a back arrow in the TopBar when the user navigates to a new screen which is not part of the BottomNavBar.

The problem now is that the onClick of the TopBar Icon is inside the main Scaffold and not inside the screen where I want to display the dialog. I only need the dialog in this one specific screen.

My MainScreen with Scaffold:

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()
    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            if (showBottomBar(navController)) {
                TopBar(title = "MainScreen", onIconClick = { } )
            }else{
                TopBar(title = "Edit Picture Screen", icon = Icons.Default.ArrowBack, onIconClick = { navController.popBackStack() }
           }

        },
        bottomBar = {
            if (showBottomBar(navController)) {
                BottomAppBar(
                    modifier = Modifier.clip(RoundedCornerShape(30.dp, 30.dp, 0.dp, 0.dp)),
                    cutoutShape = CircleShape,
                    backgroundColor = colorResource(id = R.color.purple_700),
                ) {
                    BottomNavigationBar(navController)
                }
            }
        },
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState

    ) {
        NavigationGraph(navController)
    }
}
```

My NavigationGraph (without all BottomNavBar screens):

```
@Composable
fun NavigationGraph(navController: NavHostController) {
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = BottomNavigationItem.Home.route

    ) {
        composable(BottomNavigationItem.Home.route) {
            HomeScreen()
        }
        composable(BottomNavigationItem.Edit.route) {
            EditScreen()
        }
    }
}
```

Whats the best way to call a Dialog inside of my EditScreen when the user presses the back Arrow in the TopBar and the normal backButton of the device?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea have a single `Scaffold`/`TopAppBar` because you can face this kind of problem. I prefer to encapsulate a common `TopAppBar` of my app and added it on every screen...

Comment: @nglauber I did it like that but the crossfade animation made it look bad when navigating from one to another screen.
Got the navigation-animation library from accompanist now and disabbled the animation. Now it works and looks nice.